# Trying to run a python file in flask

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to learn flask. I created a venv and installed flask. I set the flaskblog.py as FLASK_APP. But it says serving flask app 'app.py' and it fails. why is this?

I'm not sure if the image is visible. So, I'll write what I've tried below,

In the windows powershell, I cd to the directory where my venv and python script is, then

`$ . vnev\Scripts\activate`
`$ pip install flask`

```
$ set FLASK_APP=flaskblog.py

$ flask run
```

it gives me the error saying,

- Serving Flask app 'app.py' (lazy loading)
- Environment: production

  WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
- Use a production WSGI server instead.
- Debug mode: off

Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

Try 'flask run --help' for help.

Error: Could not import 'app'.

What is wrong here? I have also tried `$ setx FLASK_APP "flaskblog.py` and still get the same result. I think i created this app.py using pycharm's virtual environment and now, I cannot set other files to FLASK_APP.

What should I do?